# how can Control/write Temperature value with RS485port, from Django web?

Tags: python, django, tcp, modbus-tcp, scada

''''Hello,
I have PID **temperature controller with RS485 communication port**. I can **read & write the resister** values by connecting my 'controller' to serial PORT(com3).

I want to Monitor and **control** the room temperature from **Django-Web**.
please help me with this.
I am completely new to Django & python however somehow I managed this much with the help internet.

here is my code from where I can read and write the resister values.
''''

```
*import pymodbus
import serial
from pymodbus.pdu import ModbusRequest
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient 
from pymodbus.transaction import ModbusRtuFramer
import time,os

client= ModbusClient(method = "rtu", port="COM7",stopbits = 1, bytesize = 8, parity = 'N', baudrate=9600)
#connect to the serial modbus server
connection = client.connect()
print(connection)
pv=client.read_input_registers(6,3,unit=0x01)
print(pv.registers)
time.sleep(2)
time.sleep(2)
#set 1= 184    #controller has 3 different set points which can be seen on device's LCD display.
#set 2= 187
#set 3= 189
set=int(input("enter the set => "))
if(set==1):
address=184    #communication address for set 1
elif (set==2):
address=187    #communication address for set 2
elif (set==3):
address=190    #communication address for set 3 
else:
print("adress not recognised")
time.sleep(2)
re = client.read_holding_registers(address,3,unit=0x01)
print(re.registers)
time.sleep(2)
 
value = int(input("Enter the value => "))
result=client.write_registers(address,[value,0,0],unit=0x01) #0xB8= 184 -offset address, 0xB9=185- 
value, *3= Number of resisters
print (result)
time.sleep(3)
res = client.read_holding_registers(0xB8,5,unit=0x01)
print(res.registers)
time.sleep(10)
   
client.close()*
```

Comment: So just to be clear: you have the Modbus part working and you want to integrate it with a Django app but you don't know where to start? If that's the case I'm afraid you misunderstood the way this community works. You first need to research the topic and try something. Otherwise nobody will help you, this is not a non-for-profit sweatshop software factory.

Comment: Yes Sir, I am continuously improving my knowledge however I will need a proper guidance/instructions from this community too.